# Android fragment example for setHomeAsUpIndicator

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I am trying to adapt an Android example built for activities to fragments (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhGMd8SsA14). I want to add a Note Item in a fragment and change the actionbar. I've been fumbling around with it for a while and thought I would just ask for help.

```
public class AddNoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     ...

     @override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_note);
          ...
          getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close);
          setTitle("Add Note");
     }
}
```

I wanted to put it into a fragment and this is the closest I got:

```
public class AddScenarioFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_note_menu, menu);



        //change the title bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close);
        actionBar.setTitle("Add Scenario");


        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
}
```

But I get this error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)' on a null object reference

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to work:

```
    //reset the menu at top
    ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close);
    actionBar.setTitle("Add Scenario");
```

The ActionBar is androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar

Now I need to figure out how to deal with this in the manifest to make it function. In adapting this from an activity, I would have a statement like this:

```
<activity android:name=".AddNoteActivity" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
```

Comment: And what do I do to remove it?

Answer (score -1):

Just transfer your code from `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to the `onCreateView()` method.

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroupparent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //change the title bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close);
        actionBar.setTitle("Add Scenario");
}
```

Try with this and let me give feedback about it.

Comment: "Method does not override method from its superclass"  I guess that method is not a part of the Fragment class.

Comment: Which fragment are you using?

Comment: import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

Comment: Then it must be there, Did you find it somewhere in my link?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)

Comment: It's there. My mistake. "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205632/discussion-between-pranav-patel-and-lcj).